Add dropdown menu for zebar
I'm using GlazeWM for Windows and GlazeWM works with Zebar. I create my own widget bar using react and now i want to add something like calendar, when clicking on date widget. But that calendar can't show up beyond Zebar. How to do that?
Below is my code that calls the calendar.
import { useState, useEffect } from "react"
import { createProviderGroup } from "zebar"

import { CalendarIcon } from "lucide-react"

import { cn } from "@/lib/utils"
import { Button } from "@/components/ui/button"
import { Calendar } from "@/components/ui/calendar"
import {
    Popover,
    PopoverContent,
    PopoverTrigger,
} from "@/components/ui/popover"

const providers = createProviderGroup({
    date: { type: "date", formatting: "EEE d MMM t" },
})

const Center = () => {
    const [output, setOutput] = useState(providers.outputMap)

    useEffect(() => {
        providers.onOutput(() => setOutput(providers.outputMap));
    }, [])

    return (
        <div className="center">
            <Popover>
                <PopoverTrigger asChild>
                    <Button
                        variant={"outline"}
                        className={cn(
                            "w-[240px] justify-start text-left font-normal",
                            "text-muted-foreground"
                        )}
                    >
                        <CalendarIcon />
                        {output.date?.formatted}
                    </Button>
                </PopoverTrigger>
                <PopoverContent className="w-auto p-0 pt-1" align="start">
                    <Calendar
                        mode="single"
                        initialFocus
                    />
                </PopoverContent>
            </Popover>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Center



Create a Separate Window for the Calendar:
Try to open the calendar in a separate floating window, which is specifically designed to appear above Zebar. You can use tools like Electron to create a separate window for the calendar that will float above all other windows.
Ensure z-index is Set Properly:
If you're displaying the calendar within your main app, ensure the z-index of the calendar is set higher than that of Zebar. This will allow it to appear above the Zebar widget.
Use Electron for Creating a Window Above Zebar:
If the previous solutions are complex, consider using Electron to create a separate BrowserWindow that will be displayed above Zebar. Electron allows you to control window stacking behavior, making it easier to show your calendar window above Zebar.



This is not a bad idea, but I would like the calendar to be implemented within the framework of this project, and not separately in the electron
I set z-index to the max, but nothing has changed
Same as 1.

